# Editing code, so it could be able to accept many clients joining on the server?

Tags: java, multithreading, server, communication

I want to edit this code, so it could accept more client join on my server. This server is just used to accept one client's connection, and it can send, and receive messages. But I want to make it a "Multiplayer" Server. Many clients connected to one server. Here's the Server side code, and the Client side code:

*I would really appreciate your help!*

**My Server Code:**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class RecordAppServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final int port = 8136;
        System.out.println("Server waiting for connection on port "+port);
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
        Socket clientSocket = ss.accept();
        System.out.println("Recieved connection from "+clientSocket.getInetAddress()+" on port "+clientSocket.getPort());
        //create two threads to send and recieve from client
        RecieveFromClientThread recieve = new RecieveFromClientThread(clientSocket);
        Thread thread = new Thread(recieve);
        thread.start();
        SendToClientThread send = new SendToClientThread(clientSocket);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(send);
        thread2.start();
    }}
class RecieveFromClientThread implements Runnable
{
    Socket clientSocket=null;
    BufferedReader brBufferedReader = null;

    public RecieveFromClientThread(Socket clientSocket)
    {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    }//end constructor
    public void run() {
        try{
        brBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));       

        String messageString;
        while(true){
        while((messageString = brBufferedReader.readLine())!= null){//assign message from client to messageString
            if(messageString.equals("EXIT"))
            {
                break;//break to close socket if EXIT
            }
            System.out.println("From Client: " + messageString);//print the message from client
            //System.out.println("Please enter something to send back to client..");
        }
        this.clientSocket.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    }
    catch(Exception ex){System.out.println(ex.getMessage());}
    }
}//end class RecieveFromClientThread
class SendToClientThread implements Runnable
{
    PrintWriter pwPrintWriter;
    Socket clientSock = null;

    public SendToClientThread(Socket clientSock)
    {
        this.clientSock = clientSock;
    }
    public void run() {
        try{
        pwPrintWriter =new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(this.clientSock.getOutputStream()));//get outputstream

        while(true)
        {
            String msgToClientString = null;
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));//get userinput

            msgToClientString = input.readLine();//get message to send to client

            pwPrintWriter.println(msgToClientString);//send message to client with PrintWriter
            pwPrintWriter.flush();//flush the PrintWriter
            //System.out.println("Please enter something to send back to client..");
        }//end while
        }
        catch(Exception ex){System.out.println(ex.getMessage());}
    }//end run
}//end class SendToClientThread
```

**My Client Code:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class RecordAppClient {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            Socket sock = new Socket("192.168.0.2",8136);
            SendThread sendThread = new SendThread(sock);
            Thread thread = new Thread(sendThread);thread.start();
            RecieveThread recieveThread = new RecieveThread(sock);
            Thread thread2 =new Thread(recieveThread);thread2.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e.getMessage());} 
    }
}
class RecieveThread implements Runnable
{
    Socket sock=null;
    BufferedReader recieve=null;

    public RecieveThread(Socket sock) {
        this.sock = sock;
    }//end constructor
    public void run() {
        try{
        recieve = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.sock.getInputStream()));//get inputstream
        String msgRecieved = null;
        while((msgRecieved = recieve.readLine())!= null)
        {
            System.out.println("From Server: " + msgRecieved);
            //System.out.println("Please enter something to send to server..");
        }
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
    }//end run
}//end class recievethread
class SendThread implements Runnable
{
    Socket sock=null;
    PrintWriter print=null;
    BufferedReader brinput=null;

    public SendThread(Socket sock)
    {
        this.sock = sock;
    }//end constructor
    public void run(){
        try{
        if(sock.isConnected())
        {
            System.out.println("Client connected to "+sock.getInetAddress() + " on port "+sock.getPort());
            this.print = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), true); 
        while(true){
            //System.out.println("Type your message to send to server..type 'EXIT' to exit");
            brinput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String msgtoServerString=null;
            msgtoServerString = brinput.readLine();
            this.print.println(msgtoServerString);
            this.print.flush();

            if(msgtoServerString.equals("EXIT"))
            break;
            }//end while
        sock.close();}}catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
    }//end run method
}//end class
```

Comment: it's always better if you show us what you have done so far so that we can inspect where you were having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to implement a multithreaded server.

The general structure will be the following:

```
while(true) {
    1) Wait for client requests (Socket client = server.accept();)
    2) Create a thread with the client socket as parameter
        a) The new thread creates I/O streams (just like youre doing 
        with the PrintWriter and BufferedReader objects)
        b) Communicate with client (in your example - 
        brBufferedReader.readLine())
    3) Remove thread once the service is provided.
}
```

I suggest you take a look at the Oracle documentation:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html#multi

This might also be useful:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-multithreaded-servers/multithreaded-server.html